# PowerShell method overload resolution bug?

Tags: powershell

It seems that PowerShell method overload resolution system is not consistent with C#

Let's compare

C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass.MyMethod(false, DateTime.Now);
    }
}

public static class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod(object obj, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.MyMethod(object obj, DateTime dateTime)");
    }

    public static void MyMethod(bool b, string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass.MyMethod(bool b, string str)");
    }
}
```

vs

PowerShell

```
Add-Type `
@"
    using System;

    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static void MyMethod(object obj, DateTime dateTime)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.MyMethod(object obj, DateTime dateTime)");
        }

        public static void MyMethod(bool b, string str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyClass.MyMethod(bool b, string str)");
        }
    }
"@

[MyClass]::MyMethod($false, [DateTime]::Now)
```

C# will return

```
MyClass.MyMethod(object obj, DateTime dateTime)
```

How we expected

But PowerShell will return

```
MyClass.MyMethod(bool b, string str)
```

If we want to have the correct method called we have to be more explicit about overload we want to call

```
[MyClass]::MyMethod([object] $false, [DateTime]::Now)
```

I think it is a bug in PowerShell, not a feature

The code above was tested in PowerShell 3

In PowerShell 2 the situation is even worse. I could not find a way to call a proper overload

Even this one does not work

```
 [MyClass]::MyMethod([object] $false, [DateTime] ([DateTime]::Now))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell allows for much more type coercion than C# does.  For instance, PowerShell will coerce a DateTime to string if that is required (or an int to a bool or a string to a bool).  I suspect that the overload resolution is finding a direct type match on the first parameter and then noting the second parameter can be coerced and none of the overloads exactly match types.  That said, I happen to agree with you. I would like to see PowerShell get even better with its member overload resolution.  In this case, I would say that type compatibility should take precedence over type coercion. Of course, putting a bool in an object reference requires boxing so perhaps that knocked down the scoring for that particular overload.

Consider submitting this issue to the PowerShell team on http://connect.microsoft.com.